# How do you unpack javascript using jsbeautifier in python?

Tags: javascript, python

I have this javascript code which I want to unpack and beautify, it looks similar to this:

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=String;if('0'.replace(0,e)==0){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c];k=[function(e){return r[e]||e}];e=function(){return'^$'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('document.body.innerHTML="<iframe width=\'100%\' scrolling=\'no\' height=\'2500\' frameborder=\'0\' src=\'http://www.exmaple.com\'>";',[],1,''.split('|'),0,{}))
```

When I put this into jsbeautifier.org I get:

```
document.body.innerHTML = "<iframe width='100%' scrolling='no' height='2500' frameborder='0' src='http://www.example.com'>";
```

But when I try and use the python library (using jsbeautifier.beautify) it doesn't seem to unpack properly:

```
print al(function (p, a, c, k, e, r) {
    e = String;
    if ('0'.replace(0, e) == 0) {
        while (c--) r[e(c)] = k[c];
        k = [
            function (e) {
                return r[e] || e
            }
        ];
        e = function () {
            return '^$'
        };
        c = 1
    };
    while (c--) if (k[c]) p = p.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + e(c) + '\\b', 'g'), k[c]);
    return p
}('document.body.innerHTML="<iframe width=\'100%\' scrolling=\'no\' height=\'2500\' frameborder=\'0\' src=\'http://www.example.com\'>";', [], 1, ''.split('|'), 0, {}));
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Python code is:

```
import jsbeautifier
#script needs to have '\n' at the beginning otherwise jsbeautifier throws an error
script = """\neval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=String;if('0'.replace(0,e)==0){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c];k=[function(e){return r[e]||e}];e=function(){return'^$'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('document.body.innerHTML="<iframe width=\'100%\' scrolling=\'no\' height=\'2500\' frameborder=\'0\' src=\'http://www.example.com\'>";',[],1,''.split('|'),0,{}))"""
jsbeautifier.beautify(script)
```

Comment: What is your Python code?

Comment: It looks like it's a problem with the Python port.

Comment: Ah ok, that's annoying. I'll have to file my issues with them.

Comment: To unpack it in javascript is: eval("String" + packed_string.substr(4))

Answer (score 1):

You should import this module:

```
import jsbeautifier.unpackers.packer as packer
unpack = packer.unpack(some_packed_code)
```

I have tested this in Windows 32bit, jsbeautifier 1.54.

Answer (score 0):

jsbeautifier is broken. Use node-js (or phantomJS) instead. Working example code below:

```
import subprocess
import StringIO

data = r"""eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=String;if('0'.replace(0,e)==0){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c];k=[function(e){return r[e]||e}];e=function(){return'^$'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('document.body.innerHTML="<iframe width=\'100%\' scrolling=\'no\' height=\'2500\' frameborder=\'0\' src=\'http://www.exmaple.com\'>";',[],1,''.split('|'),0,{}))"""

data = 'console.log' + data[4:]
p = subprocess.Popen(['node'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate(data)
print stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the /n in the beginning of the string avoid the unpacker to detect the Js as packed.
try to do jsbeautifier.beautify(script.strip())

Comment: Your answer is unclear, could you elaborate on your suggestion and how it solves the problem?