# Are there any python libraries that can safely interpret obfusticated javascript strings?

Tags: javascript, python

I want to be able de-obfusticate javascript strings in python where the javascript code maybe malicious. Are there any libraries available to do this?

I started to build my own but I quickly realised it was a much bigger undertaking then I first realised. To do it properly not only do I have to safely map all the javascript string functions to python ones (including regex), I'd also have to deal with arrays, loops, variables relevant to the loop, etc.

EDIT: here's an example of what I mean

```
str1 = 'sdfhsjkdfhIdhgjkdfNgjkdfhgjkdfPdhfgkdfjUhdfjkghdfkgjTdfhgjkdfgf';
str2 = str1.replace(/[a-z]/g, '');
```

str2 should equal "INPUT"

And here's another example:

```
arr = ['-', 'M', '1', 'a', 'a', 'l', 's', 'i', 'r', 'c', 'f', 'i', '#', 'o', '[', 'u', '$', 's'];
str = ""
for (i=1; i<arr.length; i+=2) {
  str = str + arr[i];
}
```

str should be "Malicious"

Comment: @JakubM. I've added two examples so you can hopefully see the sort of thing I mean.

Comment: Just run the code in an isolated environment, let it do what it wants, and observe the result. A good bit of obfuscated code *relies* on eval. (Modern browser environments can be "safe" these days; consider jsfiddle.)

Comment: I'm trying to avoid needing a full javascript environment, if possible. It might be the only feasible option though.

Answer (score 3):

A good option is [JSBeautifier](https://github.com/einars/js-beautify/tree/master/python), which can handle most free obfuscators (actually, any obfuscator I know). There is an option to `eval` the Javascript using Rhino, but it's blacklisted by default (being unsafe).

Disclosure: I coauthored JSBeautifier, specifically I wrote the Python deobfuscation architecture. By the way, if you find some JS that JSBeautifier cannot handle, consider opening an issue on the project bugtracker :)

Comment: JSBeautifier is indeed great but there are [bugs in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613352/how-do-you-unpack-javascript-using-jsbeautifier-in-python) and it doesn't seem to do every thing I want. I'll create some example as suggested by Jakub.

Comment: Yes, I saw you posted a bug report 21 hours ago. Consider that the web version unpacks that by raw evaluation (which is disabled in the Python version). I took charge of your report.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I realise it's a lot more difficult in python were there isn't a javascript interpreter.

Comment: Actually you can enable the `evalbased` plugin and have Rhino produce the same result of the web version. But that brings a JS interpreter in action, defeating the purpose of your question. Specific unpackers understand the structure of obfuscated scripts and do not require evaluation.